# No available choices for bounty amount (on a specific question)

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties

After clicking *Start a Bounty* on [a Super User question I'd previously bountied twice](https://superuser.com/questions/258608/how-can-i-remove-the-drm-from-books-i-have-purchased-for-my-kindle) (once for 50, once for 100), I was presented with the normal dialog, but with no options in the bounty amount dropdown.

[image]

Clicking through to actually add the bounty led me to the *Page Not Found* error, presumably because it doesn't understand me trying to add a bounty for "" rep.

This doesn't seem to occur for any of my other questions, including those for which I've previously offered multiple bounties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is correct in so far that you cannot start a bounty on this question, but of course the UI shouldn't behave in that way. This will be fixed in the next build

As to *why* you can't offer a bounty: Since the minimum bounty value [is twice the amount you previously spent on a bounty on this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64826/115866), and you have offered 100 rep before, you'll have to spend at least 200 this time. However, you currently only have 147 rep on Super User.