# Minimum bounty on a question is now 100 rep?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, bounties

The first time I started a bounty I was able to choose 50, but every bounty since then the minimum is 100.  I still see other bounties of only 50.  Any idea of why I don't have the 50 option any more?  (This is across Stack Overflow and Programmers, at least.)

This is the latest answer I considered placing a bounty on  [How to populate a private container for unit test?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/119896/how-to-populate-a-private-container-for-unit-test)

That particular question does have an answer from me.

Comment: I still see all the options from 50 - 500.

Comment: The 100 minimum should only apply to the question you placed the 50 bounty on, as far as I know.

Comment: @BilltheLizard, I know other's must still be getting because I am still seeing other 50 point bounties, but I have not seen it since I started my first bounty.

Comment: @mmyers yep since 9/20/2011. see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange

Comment: @EthanFurman Oh, I didn't understand that you were placing another bounty on the same question (as mmyers pointed out).  Check on a different question and you should see 50 as an option.

Comment: @mmyers:  That's what I understand, and yet I am not getting the 50 point option when I try to start a bounty on a question that I have never started a bounty on before.  (Probably not relevant, but at least one of those question had not had *any* bounty applied before.)

Comment: @BilltheLizard:  I am not placing multiple bounties on the same question, and I am not getting the 50 point option on new (to me) questions.

Comment: Can you link to the specific question?

Comment: @BilltheLizard:  Updated with link.

Comment: I am able to select 50 as bounty, for that question.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

From the [Recent feature changes to Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59445/recent-feature-changes-to-stack-exchange) page:

> 2011-09-20: The minimum bounty on a question [you have answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack) is now
>   100.

You are posting a bounty on a question you have already answered (even though you have not previously offered a bounty on that question), so this appears to be [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

See [Waffles' answer here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64826/137484) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Hmmm -- so place the bounty and then answer... not sure that's saving a lot from the SO point-of-view.

Comment: @Ethan As you've discovered, not everyone does that. :)