# Why can't I offer a bounty of 50 reputation?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Minimum bounty on a question is now 100 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118706/minimum-bounty-on-a-question-is-now-100-rep)

Why is 50 reputation not even an option in the bounty dialog [for my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9059880/eclipse-indigo-typing-lag-on-os-x-lion)?

[The FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) states that...

> Slice off anywhere from +50 to +500 of your own hard-earned reputation
>   and attach it to any question as a bounty.

[image: screenshot of the bounty dialog]

Comment: Is it your own question? Do you have an answer on this question already?

Comment: Yes, it is my own question. No, there are no answers yet.

Comment: I was able to do it, the reason must be what Matt says.

Comment: @RoboLover: You added the bounty *as* I was adding one myself as well :).

Comment: @Matt :) And that is a great honour for me Matt, illuminating answer by the way.

Comment: Note, too, that the minimum bounty amount *doubles* each time you offer a bounty on *the same question*.

Comment: Why was the bug tag removed? waffles has stated that deleted answers should be excluded. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack/64826#comment275510_64826

Comment: `@`Kimi: If you add @NickCraver to your message, he'll get pinged and might add a comment why the bug tag was removed :).

Comment: @ Matt: ah, thanks :) Well, you heard me now @NickCraver !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The minimum amount you can offer for a bounty on a question *you* have answered is 100.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118706/minimum-bounty-on-a-question-is-now-100-rep) This was added as a small reputation hack [was discovered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack).

However, because the answer you posted has been deleted (and because [waffles commented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack#comment275510_64826) and said "I think I exclude deleted stuff"), I imagine this is a bug.

However (however), in the event of this bug being fixed (allowing you to add a bounty to  questions which has a deleted answer of yours in it), the loop hole would be renabled (in the form of deleting answer, adding bounty, undeleting answer). But it's *also* not fair that you can't add a bounty to your question in this instance.

Indeed, I fail to see what the difference is between adding a bounty to a question which you've got a zero-voted answer on (which you can't do), to adding a bounty to a question and then adding an answer to it (which you can)...

Comment: Thank you for a great answer. Has this been documented somewhere else than on waffles' answer on that question you linked?

Comment: @Kimi: Not that I know of :(.

Comment: `"Indeed, I fail to see what the difference is between adding a bounty to question which you've got a zero-voted answer on (and deleted), to adding a bounty to a question and then adding an answer to it..."` This. It doesn't feel like it's working as intended.

Comment: What Kimi said! So far the only answer my question has got is the "poor man's approach" answer I posted. So I don't see why I need to spend twice as much reputation to drive some interest, when I just trying to be helpful. (Ref: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10989848/use-a-rackspace-cloud-image-on-amazon-ec2 ) All this rule means is that in future I'll hold on to any self-answers I have just in case I want to use a bounty on the question in future. Everyone loses?