# How to award 50 rep points when the minimum bounty is 100 (apart from trivial upvoting/accept)?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

I would like to award a user some rep-points as a token of my appreciation of his efforts in helping me solving a problem ([In MATLAB exist( x, 'file' ) takes forever](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786286/matlab-exist-x-file-takes-forever)).
I already up-voted his answer, but I really wish to do a bit more.

Since his answer (although very helpful) did not solve my problem, I posted my solution, and accepted it.

As a result, I can no longer offer a bounty of 50 reputation (see, e.g.:
[Why can't I offer a bounty of 50 reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120958/why-cant-i-offer-a-bounty-of-50-reputation)).

Alas, the next possible bounty is 100 reps - and this is a bit too much for me.

Is there any way I can give the user 50 reps?

Comment: Find another exceptional answer for that user, then pass the answer bounty along that way?

Comment: While you wait for enough rep to add +100--don't go crazy with this--but I'm sure they've answered other questions that may be worth some upvotes.

Comment: Now 40 rep remaining...

Comment: You may have already done it, by posting this question: I up-voted his answer :)

Comment: @AndreaLigios - thanks!

Comment: so did I (upvote the answer)

Comment: (Heh heh; I was wondering where today's rep bump came from.) Yeah, just go and look through their (my) other answers and give a couple upvotes to answers that are up-worthy in their own right.  Other people see the activity and toss in a couple votes if the answers are widely useful, and the rep bump happens naturally through network effects. Save your bounty for when you really need it. SO's rep system is fair; no need to try to circumvent it IMHO, even for generous motivations. And thanks!

Comment: @AndrewJanke - well I really really wanted to say "thank you"! Glad you got the message.

Comment: You can also [send him a beer](http://beergivr.com/) :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Baltimore, strange.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either use our bounty system, which establishes a 100 point minimum in your case, or don't do this.  **Serial upvoting is prohibited and will be revoked within a day** if you try to pass points *that* way. Asking superfluous questions hoping your helpful answerer will answer is problematic for *so* many reasons.

Anyway, you're at 8k rep.  How did the answerer do something so extremely helpful over your SO career that is worth a 50 rep reward, but a 100 rep reward is, eh, too much?