# How do I give an answer an additional 50 bounty?

Tags: support, bounties

I thought that I could give an additional 50 bounty points for an answer if I wanted to, but it would appear that I am restricted to only giving an additional 100.  Could someone please tell me why this is so?  Is there way around this restriction?

Comment: Did you also post answer on the same question?

Comment: No, but I did write on it that if an additional task was done that wasn't critical, I'd give an additional 50 points.  You can find the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29036336/is-there-a-way-to-modify-the-style-sheet-so-that-it-transforms-an-xml-document-w/29099101).

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179409/how-to-award-50-rep-points-when-the-minimum-bounty-is-100-apart-from-trivial-up

Answer (score 0):

Either you:

1. Have already answered this question (then mininmal limit is 100)
2. Already had started a 50 rep bounty on this question before (each time the minimal bounty amount doubles)

Comment: So, I you're saying that I shouldn't have marked it as answered and then upped the bounty prior to marking it as answered?  How is that intuitive?  Why have any such restriction anyway?

Comment: @Adr Not marked, but directly *answered*. Have you answered the question you want to start the bounty on?

Comment: I had started the bounty on an unanswered question, stating that I would give an additional 50 if another criteria was met.  Someone answered with the additional criteria met, so I marked it as answered, gave the bounty, and then tried to give an additional 50 as a bounty.  I was then rebuffed by the system, saying that I could only give 100.

Comment: @Adr then look at the second point of my answer.

Comment: So you're saying that my 1st comment is correct then.  And I say again, How is that intuitive? Why have any such restriction anyway?

Comment: @Adr *Regardless*  of any answers, the bounty amount doubles each time  you want to start a new bounty.

Comment: Then I should have started another bounty and let the 1st one elapse?

Comment: [Reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/105639/201409)

Comment: @adr wut? You can't start multiple bounties simultaneously.

Comment: Ok, then there should be a mechanism to just give someone bounty points to circumvent the problem of using bounties as a way of advertising answers for extra points.

Comment: @Adrian you should have simply started a +100 bounty in the first place, not +50 if you were willing to spend 100 on it.

Comment: No I shouldn't have to.  I was willing to if certain *EXTRA* criteria was met.  Not if it was not.