# How to best donate your reputation (+ badges if possible) to other deserving users?

Tags: support, reputation, badges, bounties, donation

If someone wants to donate his/her reputation to other deserving users. How can he/she best achieve this goal? Is it possible to donate badges too, if that is what one would want to do also?

Comment: This isn't a social network. Nobody is following you.

Comment: Duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179409/how-can-i-award-a-user-with-reputation-apart-from-trivial-upvoting-accept (already voted so can't use my hammer)

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens If I edited your question to read simply "*I would love to donate my reputation to other deserving users. How can I best achieve this goal?*", do you think I would be missing any important facts?

Comment: Easily my most savage edit to date. But based on the comments above, I think I've captured the essence of the question. And I feel I had permission... :-)

Comment: I think you're really over-thinking this, @Pierre.Vriens. Just get out there and give away your reputation with bonuses. Without meaning to be rude, you don't have *thousands* of points to distribute. A lot of people have spent a lot of time reading this question, comments etc., so I recommend you just delete this question and go off donating. Post a new question if you get stuck somehow.

Comment: Think over `Will my spouse suffer from my negative SE reputation?`.

Answer (score 5):

> I would love to donate my reputation to other deserving users. How can I best achieve this goal?

Do a bounty! Bounties can ***only be given to answers!*** You can sacrifice some of your rep and "donate" that rep to another users. There are many reasons, including:

> One or more of the answers is exemplary and worthy of an additional bounty.

That means that you think that an answer is so good, the user should receive a bounty from you. Of course, don't give too much of your rep or you will never give bounties again... Example of giving a bounty is this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted), where the top three answers got at least a +50 rep bounty, with the top one a +650 rep bounty. Giving a bounty means giving a user a piece of your rep that is divisible by 50. No exceptions and no takebacks.

You can simply vote up their post. Voting up a question gives the OP +5 rep. Voting an answer up and the user who wrote that answer gets +10 rep. Downvoting on the other hand, will only make the user lose -2 rep.

> I would also like to donate badges too, is this possible?

Nope. You can't. If you want to try, ask Jon Skeet. You will see why.

## Conclusion

Do a bounty or just plain old vote up that post. This ain't a game where you can just give rep and badges like a trading card game! I hope this helps you!