# What should we do about our [donation]s?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, ambiguous-tags

The [donation](/questions/tagged/donation) tag has 21 questions and no tag wiki or usage guidance. The questions tagged with it vary from inquiries about donating *to* Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow, the Stack Gives Back event, or feature requests relating to users donating to others (whether those donations be [reputation/badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251622/622284) or [actual money](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78396/622284)). It's pretty ambiguous, feels meta-taggy, and without a proper tag wiki/usage guidance, it leaves a lot to be desired.

Stack Gives Back seems like a topic worthy of its own tag, given that there are quite a few questions about it/suggestions for it, and it seems to be sticking around as a yearly event.

I feel as though the [donation](/questions/tagged/donation) tag should probably be purely about donations to Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow, or other donations that SE should give/has given to other entities (here's [an example](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/46920/622284)), while a new tag is created, [stack-gives-back](/questions/tagged/stack-gives-back), that is solely focused on the Stack Gives Back event.

What are your thoughts? Does that sound reasonable, or should we do something else?

Comment: Can I make a [donation] toward tag work?

Comment: Short answer:  That sounds perfectly reasonable to me.