# Is it possible to offer more points for a bounty that is already offered?

Tags: support, bounties

I do not believe one of my bounties is receiving enough attention despite the bounty given for it. Is it possible to add the amount of points in a bounty to attract more attention during the bounty offering period?

Example of case: you give e.g. +50 bounty and after some time elapsed it is still not getting answered. You think you'll want to add +100 points to make it worth of +150 to call for more eyes to look it. Is this possible and what are the scenarios to attract that extra attention.

My opinion is that all bounties with only +50 points aren't that attractive and adding the amount will attract more attention.

What are the ways of calling new attention? Is it possible to give more points to the same bounty? Is it possible to create two bounties to same question and are these then combined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this isn't possible.  You would have to wait and set a new bounty after the first one has expired.  The minimum value for it this time will be 100 points (which doubles on each successive bounty you post on the same question).  You will find more information in the [bounties FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).

In terms of other ways to attract attention, you might find help in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions).  In summary other than offering bounties you should:

> edit the question to provide status and progress updates resulting from your own continued efforts to answer the question yourself. I usually do that unless I really hit a dead end with no further clues to follow.

Comment: Sorry for the overkill of 3 answers, live-updating didn't work for me there.

Comment: Apparently it was the most helpful, so no problem at all. :D

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't increase your current bounty. Once the bounty is over you can offer a new bounty though. This automatically has to be higher than your previous bounty.

From ["How does the bounty system work"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

> Note that if you offer several bounties on the same question, [you will
>   have to double the amount each time (or more)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/abusing-bounties-for-unlimited-profit/105639#105639). That is, if your first
>   bounty was worth 50 reputation, your second bounty on the same
>   question will have to be for at least 100, your third for at least 200
>   and so on. If you've already offered a bounty for more than 250, you
>   can still offer more bounties for 500 (the maximum amount) as long as
>   you like (or as long as you have the rep). This doubling applies only
>   to bounties by the same user on the same question.

Comment: I opened a bounty to DIFFERENT question while I had an bounty open in another. There I also had a minimum of +100 while the first was wort of +50. Is that a bug?

Comment: Hmm, I am not sure. I can't find an entry explaining that behavior. Nor do I have an open bounty myself to try it.

Comment: I had my own answer in the second question. That raises the minimum. [http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118706/minimum-bounty-on-a-question-is-now-100-rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118706/minimum-bounty-on-a-question-is-now-100-rep)

Comment: Ah yes, that's true. Forgot about that one. :) Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to give more points to the same bounty?

No, it isn't. The value of the bounty is fixed throughout its lifetime.

> Is it possible to create two bounties to same question and are these then combined?

No - only one bounty can be active on a question at any one time.

---

Once the bounty has finished, you can offer *another* bounty with more rep attached.

I suggest reading through [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work).