# Can not start a bounty after answering it

Tags: bug, questions, bounties

I got a question with a couple of upvotes I want to set a bounty on. I have set bounties before, but this time I have a problem. Instead of getting the usual start bounty tag, I get the date it was eligible for bounty. In my case half a month ago.

One of the complications may be that I answered my own question with a sort of solution. Even though I deleted this answer I still can not get it to start the bounty.

I really want to set a bounty on the question. My current reputation is above 90, so it is not the lack of reputation.

I do not know if it is just a bug or if it is impossible to set a bounty to a question already answered by yourself. If you need the link it is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143067/remove-extra-space-around-gridview-programmatically).

Edit:

This is how it looks for me:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I can see the bounty link as well as your deleted answer, however, it is not really deleted.

Comment: I undeleted it but nothing happened, so I added it again

Comment: then you havn't mentioned that (little) information in the above question (however i dont think if it is necessary or not).

Comment: I delete it now

Comment: well i can still see the same link of "start bounty", may be moderator can light on this.

Comment: *"I get the date it was eligible for bounty"* ... could you add a screenshot of this? I have never seen this happen.

Comment: Added picture in new edit

Comment: You need [75 reputation points](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) in order to start a bounty, but you have 92 so that should be enough. Have you recently earned these points?

Comment: I see that you have awarded a bounty of 50 on another question before. Might it be that the system somehow thinks your next bounty should be 100 minimum? (Bug perhaps?) Anyway, just guessing here. Can't explain the behaviour at the moment.

Comment: @ChrisF I have not earned a lot of points recently. Have had about 80 for a while.

Comment: @Bart think it stands something else then eligable for bounty at a date, if you do not have enough reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will not let you start a bounty on the question because it requires a minimum of 100 points to start a bounty on a question that you answered, which you do not have.

[Minimum bounty on a question is now 100 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118706/minimum-bounty-on-a-question-is-now-100-rep)

Probably because your answer is only soft-deleted, the bounty system still sees it as a question you answered, and is requiring 100 points to set the bounty.

Comment: So I need to use 50 extra reputation just because I answeared my question with a walkaround? Since somebody gave me a upvote can I now start a bounty for 100 reputation.

Comment: Unfortunately, yes.  I ran into this exact problem when I was awarded a bounty of 100 points and wanted to split it with another user, but it wouldn't let me set a 50 point bounty because I had answered the question.

Comment: The bounty is now running at 100 reputation!