# Why Is There No "Start Bounty" Link On My Question?

Tags: support, bounties

I would like to offer a bounty on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11923208/781200). All the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) criteria seem fulfilled (enough points, no other bounties etc). There is an 'eligible for bounty' link that points to the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty). But no 'Start Bounty' link.

Why would this be?

Comment: I see a "start a bounty" button below the comments, shows the "start a bounty" popup when I click it.

Comment: It's really not there for me.

Comment: Seems you were successful. So what did you do?

Comment: All I did was ask this question and looked around, gaining a few more points. I really have no idea why it reappeared.

Comment: I am getting used to etiquette here and wonder - I guess I do not accept any answer here because no answer contained the answer (ie explanation). Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, don't worry about it. I might harass you about your accept rate after a while, but those comments are easily nuked anyway. ;) Nah, no answer, not accept I would say.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The minimum bounty amount you can offer on a question that you've answered is 100 reputation points.  This is to prevent gaming of the bounty system, as described here: [Clever bounty reputation hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack/64826#64826)

> If you are placing a bounty on a question you answered, your minimum spend is 100

Since you had already posted your answer,  you couldn't offer the bounty until you'd crossed the 101 rep threshold ([you mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143714/why-is-there-no-start-bounty-link-on-my-question#comment408909_143717) you were at 97 rep when you couldn't see the bounty link).

Mystery solved!

Comment: (Note: I was not, in any way, accusing *you* of trying to game the bounty system.  I hope it didn't come across that way)

Comment: It didn't come across as that at all. Thanks for resolving the mystery. Answer accepted!

Answer (score 1):

The start bounty link has appeared. It certainly wasn't there when I asked this question. I do not know why it appeared but I had gained more points (122) in the meantime (so not the 125 that frederic suggested might help).

Comment: How much your reputation when you were unable to see link?

Comment: My rep was 97 when I failed to see the link and 122 when I saw it.