# Bounty starts from 100 rep, rather than 50?

Tags: support, bounties, active-bounties

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

I started a bounty on
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14471276/is-it-possible-to-debug-mex-code-with-eclipse) but I could not set it to 50 rep - only to 100.

I understand from the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) that it is possible to start a bounty for 50 rep (I'm cheap - what can I say?)

My questions are

1. Why wasn't I able to choose 50 rep for the bounty? (I could only choose 100 or more)
2. Is there a way to correct the bounty to 50 now that it is already "in the open"?

**EDIT:**
The question I put a bounty for is only **two days old** and apparently this is the first bounty offered for it (to the best of my limited knowledge).

Comment: Why were you not able to start a bounty of 50 rep? Did you get any error message whey trying to start a bounty of 50 rep? Or you did not get an option for 50 rep?

Comment: There was a bounty on there previously; new bounties must be at least double the previous bounty.

Comment: @hims056 - I did not get any error, I simply did not have the choice to 50 at the drop box - it started from 50 and went up.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - I was not aware of any bounty on this question before. It is fairly new (only **2 days old**) with very little views. Is there any way of knowing "bounty history" for a question?

Comment: And related: ["Abusing" bounties for unlimited profit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105275/105639#105639)

Comment: @Shai: I can't see whom set the previous bounty on that question because you set a bounty on it now. Normally I look at the [question history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14471276/revisions). The fact that you had to set a 100 point minimum is the only evidence I have right now there was a previous bounty.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - it is highly unlikely that a bounty existed there. since this question is only **two days old** and it is eligible for a bounty for the **first time** today! So, despite the nice answer you referred me to - I do not believe this is the case here.

Comment: @Shai: I must confess that I am now puzzled, but there is no other way the system would raise the minimum bounty amount.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - should I add [tag:bug]?

Comment: @Shai: Let's see if any moderators respond; they have more information at their disposal. I'm but a regular user, I also may be wrong about my conclusions.

Comment: @MartijnPieters - at any rate, thank you very much for your comments, they are very helpful.

Comment: you posted [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14473617/839601) there, before starting bounty: "**Note:** If you are offering a bounty on a question that *you* have already posted an answer to, [your minimum spend is 100 reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack/64826#64826) (not 50)." - quoted from [How does the bounty system work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)

Comment: @Shai - Don't answer in the question. Let Gnat answer the question. :)

Comment: @Shai [single bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1714410/shai?tab=bounties&sort=offered "you offered so far") is too little to gain knowledge about all the perversions about this system. :) As an example, it took me [20 or something](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/165773/gnat?tab=bounties&sort=offered "of 63 offered as of now") before I learned not to become frustrated with every new twist of the rules I discover

Comment: @gnat - You are the master of the bounty system on Meta! :) You maintain your reputation to 3000. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14473617/839601) there, before starting bounty:

> **Note:** If you are offering a bounty on a question that *you* have already posted an answer to, [your minimum spend is 100 reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack/64826#64826) (not 50).

Above is quoted from [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)