# Any way to attract attention to a good answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, answers

For questions, you can attract attention by offering a bounty.

Now let's say you worked hard and offered what you feel is a very good answer (possibly a lot better than the currently accepted answer) - problem is - no one's looking at it - especially if there are already many answers with up-votes and with an accepted answer.

Is there any way to attract attention to it?

**EDIT:**

Feature request: What if we could ask for moderator attention for good answers (as well) possibly for a cost of some points - after which the moderators could decide to either reject the claim that it is a very good answer or distinguish it in some way - if it is indeed a good answer...like for example to display it as the first answer or the like.

Comment: There's a specific bounty reason for that

Comment: I mean, for the *poster of the answer* to attract attention

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate of either of those questions. Over there, the asker wants to draw attention to someone else's answer on his question. Here, I asked the opposite: draw atttention to *my answer* on someone else's quesion

Comment: Agreed it's not a duplicate, voting to reopen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Edit is the main way for answers. Once posted it will bump the whole question to the front page so it will not go unnoticed, and after a while you can improve the answer by editing, thus bumping again to the front page.

Bounty for the question as others suggested will also bump it to the front, but won't highlight your answer (i.e. the latest activity was done on the question itself). If it's good enough though, people will notice.

Also, you can and welcome to share your answer on Twitter, Facebook or Google+:

> [image]

The more it's linked, the merrier.

All in all, no need to be worried - just let it stay there and people will find it while searching. I still get upvoted on answers I posted years ago.

Answer (score 3):

There is [Clever Bounty Reputation Hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64824/173052) from old days... In your situation

1. Make some research and improve your answer
2. Format it well with bold strings, listed items etc. **A well formatted text** attracts attention! Even people who thinks your answer is long will read the **bold** parts and *listed items*. If your formatting is good and you choose the right sections of your answer for text styling, probably you get enough attention for an upvote.
3. Then open a bounty for the question.

Comment: … a well formatted text **does not** need to make use of **bold** items which usually **throws** readers off. If anything, formatting's being **abused** too much these days.

Comment: I does not need to use bold always, but in some situations it is good to use it. But these are all my opinion on the subject though.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually award a bounty to an answer of your choosing. Being able to award a bounty to yourself would be pointless though.

A well-written answer will eventually attract the attention it deserves.

Comment: I like the use of 'eventually' here. Most users with a reasonable amount of participation have that small collection of answers that keep getting up-voted a few times each week which were written years ago. It's neat to know something you barely remember writing continues to help that many people over that length of time.