# Why should you spend a minimum of 100 reputation to a question that you have already answered?

Tags: discussion, bounties

In the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

I don't understand, it also states

> You cannot award a bounty to your own answer.

So, what's the point of requiring a minimum of 100 reputation points?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You cannot award a bounty to your own answer, however by posting a bounty you can generate considerable attention to the question. Which in turn may give you more than 5 upvotes equal to 50 points (considering the quality and usefulness of your answer). In a way you invested 50 points to capture attention, which may give you more reps (profit). To avoid this kind of rep harvesting, this restriction is in place.

Comment: Reference worth reading: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64826/152859.