# Don't set minimum bounty to 100 when own answer is community wiki

Tags: feature-request, reputation, answers, bounties, community-wiki

If you have answered your own question, and want to start a bounty on it, you must start at 100 rep instead of the default 50, [because:](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/bounty)

> To avoid overly promotional bounties, if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted an answer to, your minimum spend is 100 reputation (not 50).

This is true even if your answer is community wiki and you would earn exactly zero rep from it. This makes no sense. I suggest that the condition be modified to "if you are offering a bounty on a question that you have already posted a *non-community-wiki* answer to, ..."

---

True story: I recently asked a question to which I later found an elegant solution buried in the answers to a slightly different question. My question is not a duplicate of one the solution was posted as an answer to, so I have reposted the solution as a community wiki answer and accepted it. In the meantime, another user posted an alternative answer that, while not the solution I would prefer to use in practice, is extremely cool and I want to reward them for it. I don't want to mark it as the accepted answer, but I'd like to give them a bounty of 50 rep instead. I don't see why I should be required to spend 100 rep in these circumstances.

Comment: It's not just the reputation that you gain from up-votes. The fact the answer is CW doesn't change the _overly promotional_ part: With the bounty you are still getting more eyes over a question you answered.

Comment: @kiamlaluno Which is rather backwards if you think about it, as certainly 100 will get "more eyes" than 50. Although I fail to see how "more eyes" causes a tangible problem anyways.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: And how is that different from a bounty on a question I did not answer?

Comment: The difference is that you aren't (supposedly) being overly promotional for your answer.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: So it's OK to be promotional for your question, but not for your answer? Note that in [the original motivation for the 100 minimum](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64824/152819), self-promotion was indeed interpreted in terms of reputation gain.