# Can I answer a question I've put a bounty on?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

Let's say I find a good question on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) then decide to post a bounty on it. A few days later I then stumble upon a solution and decide I want to post an answer.

[I know the minimum bounty for a question you've previously answered is doubled from 50 to 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64826/351462). But what happens if I put a 50 rep bounty on a question then want to answer afterwards?

Am I able to post an answer while my bounty is still active? Or is there a cooldown period before I'm able to answer?

Comment: You can answer yourself at any time, but you cannot award the bounty to yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Placing a bounty does not prohibit you from answering or performing most other actions (by the way, you can also do the reverse – answer then place bounty – it does not matter, although, as you note, answering first does raise the *minimum* bounty from 50 to 100).

However, [you cannot award the bounty to yourself](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/54998/i-just-awarded-myself-a-bounty/97802#97802), only the other answers will be considered for the bounty.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's worth noting that the order does matter, as answering first will [raise the minimum bounty from 50 to 100](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64824/clever-bounty-reputation-hack/64826#64826).

Comment: Well, it does prevent closing the question. :)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro It affects the *minimum*, not the overall cost. You'll still pay 100 points to offer a 100 point bounty regardless of the order, there's no "tax".

Comment: I sometimes offer a bounty to a question to solicit feedback on the quality of the question itself.