# Update/recreate question with unhelpful answers

Tags: discussion, edits, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I asked a question a couple of months ago:

[How to mitigate risk of having cash with you when abroad?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/158731/how-to-mitigate-risk-of-having-cash-with-you-when-abroad)

The answers were unhelpful ...as I added on a comment:

> "be street-smart" and similar suggestions, is in the remit of travel.stackexchange.com, and I purposefully asked the question here, and not on the travel subsite, because I hoped to get answers on how to deal with the "move money securely without having it physically on my person" side of the problem, not on the "avoid getting mugged while travelling" side of the problem

I also understand that adding more details to the question might've made it easier to be answered, but unfortunately at the time I decided to omit several details (including mentioning the country that I was going to travel to, which could've helped with providing information specific about the banking system of that country), since after all, I found it unwise to write publicly on the internet about the fact that I was going to travel with more cash than I was comfortable with, in a relatively small country (it was the UAE), or the reason why I had to travel with cash (which are basically the same reason as in [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/125991/how-to-transfer-money-from-russia-to-germany)). That travel is now in the past, and I can thus disclose that information, as well as provide my own answer re. what I ended up doing, which is still a very suboptimal solution.

I would like to add those bits of information, and hopefully that could also be used by more people that are familiar with solutions to the problem.

Unfortunately, simply adding details to an old question that already got answers is likely to not get enough attention. Not to mention that keeping the old question up would reward the badly written answers.

I made sure that the old question is [archived on the internet archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20230000000000*/https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/158731/how-to-mitigate-risk-of-having-cash-with-you-when-abroad), I drafted the new version of my question and... before submitting it, I tried to delete the old question.

Unfortunately, it seems it's not possible for me to delete the old question.

I could still ignore this, and submit the new question anyhow ... but I was even planning for it to have the exactly same title, and I thus expect that doing so without deleting the old question would lead to it being ignored/closed as duplicate very, very quickly.

Comment: I just noticed this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer ... unfortunately it was not suggested when I typed my above question

Comment: One of the suggestions in that other question is: create a bounty. I didn't consider it because I never did it before, but this has a problem: if I provide my own answer, I won't be able to create the bounty: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64826 (this is because, even if I had 100 reputation carried over from my other profile, because I am new to this specific subsite, and because people downvoted me, I don't have 100 reputation to offer for the bounty anymore).

Comment: You've meanwhile self-answered the question. Would that suffice for you?

Comment: Except that I cannot create a bounty on the question, yes

Comment: @berdario but in case you want more answers, you can still start a bounty. To keep your basic privileges (e.g. commenting anywhere) put only 50 to it, not 100, but it's totally valid and possible.

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda you're wrong, check my link above. If you added an answer, the minimum is 100 (in the meanwhile, thankfully someone upvoted me, so I've been able to actually reach the minimum)

Comment: @berdario oh, I see now, and you are correct. Sorry!

Comment: "Unfortunately, simply adding details to an old question that already got answers is likely to not get enough attention. Not to mention that keeping the old question up would reward the badly written answers." I don't understand why you believe either of these to be the case.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel "likely to not get enough attention": just look at the question I referred to. After my update there have been no new answers, despite me offering a bounty (I understand that nothing is guaranteed, but my point stands). About the fact it would "reward the badly written answers": again, look at the same question, the currently most upvoted answer (with 5 points/upvotes) boils down to "A bank would probably [send money home]", which is imprecise, probably most often false (if you're not an existing customer) and unactionable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Beyond the advice given in [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7046/158100) I'll address two of your concerns:

> simply adding details to an old question that already got answers is likely to not get enough attention.

I'm not sure whose attention you're hoping for. Active users might well have filters, subscriptions or are watching their tags for activity and an edit definitely put the Q/A on their radar. Beyond that, most traffic comes from Google so they will find your question and their answers which is lots of attention in the long run.

> Not to mention that keeping the old question up would reward the badly written answers.

You're not the one to decide whether an answer is badly written or not. That is left for the voters. And given you now self admit the question was originally lacking details (for valid reasons) it is a bit weird to fully blame an answer for not being on par. With the info you now can reveal the answerer could have done a better / more tailored response and they still might.

Last points of advice:

- If you edit your question, which I suggest you do, make sure to not invalidate the existing answers.
- you could check on the meta of Money first to see if they have specific guidance / advice on editing or re-posting.